# Unable to find the requested track - 'Open testing'

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console, fastlane, android-app-bundle

I am trying to automatically upload builds to the `Open Testing track` in Play Store using fastlane's `upload_to_playstore`. When i use the track "Open testing" it does not find any track for it. How can you go about using Fastlane to upload to Open Testing?

It seems that the only options are: production(public), beta(Closed Testing - Beta), alpha(Closed Testing - Alpha), internal(Internal Testing).

This is how it looks like on the Google Play Console:
[image]

My lane:

```
  desc "Deploy a new version to the OPEN TESTING TRACK Google Play"
  lane :upload_to_open_testing_play_store do
    # gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    upload_to_play_store(
       aab: ENV["PLAY_STORE_AAB_PATH"], 
       track: 'Open testing',
       release_status: 'completed',
       skip_upload_aab: true,
       version_code: 28
    )
  end
```

Error:

```
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7184370Z [22:24:01]: [32mDriving the lane 'android upload_to_open_testing_play_store' [0m
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7184800Z [22:24:01]: [32m----------------------------------[0m
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7185330Z [22:24:01]: [32m--- Step: upload_to_play_store ---[0m
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7185600Z [22:24:01]: [32m----------------------------------[0m
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7185690Z 
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7203070Z +------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7203460Z |                                                                            [32mSummary for supply 2.212.2[0m                                                                            |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7203820Z +------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7204560Z | aab                                | /pathto/app-release.aab                                       |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7204730Z | track                              | Open testing                                                                                                                                |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7204860Z | release_status                     | completed                                                                                                                                   |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7204990Z | skip_upload_aab                    | true                                                                                                                                        |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7205110Z | version_code                       | 28                                                                                                                                          |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7205280Z | package_name                       | com.blabla.test                                                                                                               |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7205450Z | metadata_path                      | ./fastlane/metadata/android                                                                                                                 |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7205780Z | json_key                           | /Users/blabla/azagents/secure_files/play_store_service_account_api_key/jsonkeysecure.json |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7206010Z | skip_upload_apk                    | false                                                                                                                                       |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7206170Z | skip_upload_metadata               | false                                                                                                                                       |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7206390Z | skip_upload_changelogs             | false                                                                                                                                       |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7206540Z | skip_upload_images                 | false                                                                                                                                       |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7206660Z | skip_upload_screenshots            | false                                                                                                                                       |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7206790Z | track_promote_release_status       | completed                                                                                                                                   |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7208200Z | validate_only                      | false                                                                                                                                       |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7208490Z | check_superseded_tracks            | false                                                                                                                                       |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7208610Z | timeout                            | 300                                                                                                                                         |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7208730Z | deactivate_on_promote              | true                                                                                                                                        |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7208850Z | changes_not_sent_for_review        | false                                                                                                                                       |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7208990Z | rescue_changes_not_sent_for_review | true                                                                                                                                        |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7209210Z | ack_bundle_installation_warning    | false                                                                                                                                       |
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7209530Z +------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2023-05-17T19:24:01.7209670Z 
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1661850Z +------------------+-------------------------------------------+
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1671850Z |                         [33mLane Context[0m                         |
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1673020Z +------------------+-------------------------------------------+
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1673570Z | DEFAULT_PLATFORM | android                                   |
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1676400Z | PLATFORM_NAME    | android                                   |
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1676850Z | LANE_NAME        | android upload_to_open_testing_play_store |
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1677620Z +------------------+-------------------------------------------+
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1685190Z [22:24:04]: [31mUnable to find the requested track - 'Open testing'[0m
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1685470Z 
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1698040Z +------+----------------------+-------------+
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1698760Z |             [32mfastlane summary[0m              |
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1699300Z +------+----------------------+-------------+
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1699690Z | Step | Action               | Time (in s) |
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1700330Z +------+----------------------+-------------+
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1700790Z | 1    | default_platform     | 0           |
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1707960Z |    | [31mupload_to_play_store[0m | 2           |
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1710850Z +------+----------------------+-------------+
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1711400Z 
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1712010Z [22:24:04]: [31mfastlane finished with errors[0m
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1716630Z [31m
2023-05-17T19:24:04.1721620Z [!] Unable to find the requested track - 'Open testing'[0m
```